# mypy and Django type checking

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mypy

I'm trying to enable type hints for my Django REST project. I installed `django-stubs` and `djangorestframework-stubs` and I have the following `mypy.ini` file:

```
[mypy]
plugins =
    mypy_django_plugin.main
    mypy_drf_plugin.main

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = "core.settings.base"
```

Some of the type hints do work; for example, if I have a variable inside of a method whose type is a model class, I get hints when I try to access a field or method defined on it.

However, if I try to access a Django-specific field on the model, for example a reverse relation, that does not typecheck and gives me an error. Moreover, if I try to access fields on a related model of my model variable, the related object has type `Any`

For example, with these two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role) # definition of Role model not relevant

class Badge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="badges")
```

then this will happen:

```
u: User = get_user()
print(u.name) # correctly hinted and typechecks
print(u.badges.all()) # type error
print(u.role.pk) # no hint on role.pk, role is Any
```

How do I get my project to correclty type check all the Django-specific features such as foreign key fields, querysets, and reverse relationships?

Comment: Short answer, wait for https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/ in 3.11 which will have some improvements on this area, its still a bit unclear how much it will solve for Django models.

Comment: Another caveat is that your current setup only works for Mypy checker. Other checkers i.e the one shipped with VS Code will not use the mypy plugin and wont work, how do you run your type checks?

Comment: I don't actually *run* them, I just use the intellisense + highlighting done by VSC. How would you setup django-stubs for the checker that comes with VSC? The docs on that package seem to be biased towards using mypy

Comment: The stub works, but the mypy-plugins that you added are not used by pyright, which is the MS built in python type checker and totally separate software from mypy, and the plugins are needed for django models to be correctly typed without any extra code.